# Laravel only update if not null

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a way of condensing the following code into a single `update()`?:

```
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users,email,'.$id,
        'password' => 'nullable|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'timezone' => 'required|timezone',
    ]);

    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    $user->update(request()->all());
    if (!empty(request()->input('password'))) {
        $user->update(['password' => bcrypt(request()->input('password'))]);
    }
```

I want to get rid of the conditional statement for updating the password because I am using a mutator to `bcrypt` it automatically now. Is there a method like `request()->allNotNull()`?

Comment: That won't solve your problem, because you still need to `bcrypt()` your password? Also which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: The password is bcrypted with a mutator now....sorry should have mentioned that.

Comment: Then @Alexey's answer is perfect.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$user = User::where('id', $id)->update(request()->all());
```

Maybe you'll also want to add `->take(1)`.

**Update**

In comments you've said you want to get rid of empty fields. Use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
array_filter($request->all());
```

> If no callback is supplied, all entries of array equal to `false` will be removed.

Comment: I want to get rid of the conditional statement for updating the password because I am using a mutator to `bcrypt` it automatically now. Is there a method like `request()->allNotNull()`?

Comment: request does not have a filter method. The request object must be converted to a collection before.

Comment: @oseintow silly me. Of course, it doesn't. Updated the answer with `array_filer` solution which does exactly the same job (`filter()` uses `array_filter()`). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this. Password will be filtered out if password is empty.

```
$input = collect(request()->all())->filter()->all();

$user = User::where('id', $id)->update($input);
```

Comment: Or just `$input = array_filter($request->all())` since al `filter()` does is using `array_filter()`.